# Object gets overridden - Angular 4 - simple

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

It's the end of the day and can't think right now. I am dynamically adding an array and properties to an object that I have created. I would like for instead of the object's array to be overridden I would like for a new instance of the object to be created. I will iterate through this function multiple times and newObj get overridden with the latest data, rather than on top of one another.

Object

```
newObj: any = {
    name: 'Unassigned',
    items: [],
  }
```

The rest of the code

```
sortItems($event: any){

    this.newObj.name = $event[0].name
    this.newObj.items.push($event[0], this.dragData)
    console.log(this.newObj, 'added items')

    //adding object to trips
    this.items.forEach((res, i) => {
      if(res.itemId == $event[0].itemId){
        return this.items.splice(i + 1, 0, this.newObj)
      }
    })


  }
```

Comment: Are you sure they have different Id's?

Comment: Basically what happens is the items doubles, instead the overall object should be duplicated, but obviously not have the same data.

Comment: If you add a working example I might be able to help more, I can't figure out what is wrong with what you currently have posted @userlkjsflkdsvm